# Is there a way to prevent website text from being searchable?

Tags: javascript, css, search, web

When searching with `Ctrl + F` in a website I'd like to exclude some text. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I doubt it. What is the specific use case?

Comment: I developed this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vertabs/ohogedbookenkamipehdjkeilonagpcp and would like to exclude the injected text.

Comment: Yup, use images or a canvas ;)

Comment: Or add some white 1px texts between each two characters.

Comment: @IanKuca I like the canvas idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Apparently

Some quick testing shows that text content added via a pseudo-element will not be found. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYzyN/4/)** (search "Google" as an example) which uses the following example code (HTML5). I realize you may want to use `a` tags or something else, and may need to use javascript for functionality, but the point is, you can make small amounts of text, as you seem to require, that is invisible to searching.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="hideText">
    <li data-cB="Google" data-cA="https://www.google.se"></li>
    <li data-cB="GitHub" data-cA="https://github.com"></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.hideText {list-style: none}
.hideText li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-top-color: #eee;
    border-left-color: #eee;
}
.hideText li:before {
    content: attr(data-cB);
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.hideText li:after{
    content: attr(data-cA);
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This will do it :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling this is a little out of the scope of this question but there is a forum post on Mozillazine discussing how Google had overridden the Cmd-F. The post is here

[forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=2011073](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=2011073)

And here is a bug report discussing how websites should never be allowed to capture command shortcuts

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=459744

I would suggest that you use images or canvas for the text you don't want people to Cmd-F, as this will get your desired result.